# How to track changes with the comment box on the cells after updating from the userform?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to write a VBA macro to track changes of a worksheet in a separate sheet(showing the history of changes) by displaying a comment box on the cell with some color, automatically when the user search and updates the data in the userform.

Below code is for search and update:

''this code is for updating the data in the userform''

```
Private Sub cmdupdate_Click()
If Me.TextBox1.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "SL No Can Not be Blank!!!", vbExclamation, "SL No"
Exit Sub
End If
SLNo = Me.TextBox1.Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Dim rowselect As Double
rowselect = Me.TextBox1.Value
rowselect = rowselect + 1
Rows(rowselect).Select
Cells(rowselect, 2) = Me.TextBox2.Value
Cells(rowselect, 3) = Me.TextBox3.Value
Cells(rowselect, 4) = Me.TextBox4.Value
Cells(rowselect, 5) = Me.TextBox5.Value
Cells(rowselect, 6) = Me.TextBox6.Value

End Sub
```

''The below code is used to search from the excel sheet and displays in the userform''

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Do
        DoEvents
        row_number = row_number + 1
        item_in_review = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row_number)
        If item_in_review = TextBox1.Text Then
            TextBox2.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & row_number)
            TextBox3.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & row_number)
            TextBox4.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & row_number)
            TextBox5.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & row_number)
            TextBox6.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & row_number)
        End If
    Loop Until item_in_review = ""
End Sub
```

Now I try to add the below code for track changes after updating the excel sheet with userform but I am getting an error in this line "Target.Comment.Text Text:=OldVal" not able to get the solution to complete my task.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim X As Integer
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
        ShtName = "Edits Log"
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    X = EndRow + 1
    Wb.Sheets(ShtName).Range("A" & X).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
    Wb.Sheets(ShtName).Range("B" & X).Value = Target.Address
    Wb.Sheets(ShtName).Range("C" & X).Value = OldVal
    Wb.Sheets(ShtName).Range("D" & X).Value = Target.Value
    Wb.Sheets(ShtName).Range("E" & X).Value = Now()
    Wb.Sheets(ShtName).Range("F" & X).Value = Environ("username")
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    On Error Resume Next
    Target.AddComment
    On Error GoTo 0
    Target.Comment.Visible = False
    Target.Comment.Text Text:=OldVal
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    OldVal = Target.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Have your tried setting the visibility of the comment to `false` *after* inserting the text?

Comment: Yes it is false

Comment: I can see that. I am asking if you tried moving the line setting it to false **AFTER** inserting the text

Comment: What is the value of `OldVal`?

Comment: Value of Oldval is showing Empty

Comment: Where do you declare `OldVal`? Is it a `Public` variable? Assuming it is, if the selection is changed to an empty cell, `OldVal` will be empty, and then you won't be able to use as the text of a comment.

Comment: Yes Oldval is a public variant

Comment: The cells are getting highlightend with yellow color but the comment box is empty and in "Edits Log" sheet the track records are not visible.

Comment: @Santo - How and where is `Oldval` declared?

Comment: I declared before this line "Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" as Public Oldval As String.

Comment: @Santo if you are tracking the changes in a cell, if the cell was previously empty then `oldVal` will be Empty. `Cstr(oldVal)` will then produce an empty string, and then you'll have a blank comment if you use that as the comment's text.

Comment: Yes i tried now but the same problem i.e. cells are getiing highlighted but the comment box is empty.

Comment: Then how i can get the oldval as a text in the comment box,

Comment: @Santo, if you change a non-blank cell, is the added comment still blank?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, the error is thrown because `oldVal` is `Empty`. When a previously blank cell is changed, the `Selection Change` fires, and since there was no previous value in the cell, `oldVal` will be `Empty`.

The `Worksheet Change` code needs to handle that possibility, as well as the possibility that `Target` contains an error - e.g. #VALUE! or #N/A.

Stripping out the portion that writes to the "Edits Log" tab, your `Worksheet Change` might look something like the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Public oldVal 'should be a Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    oldVal = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

    On Error Resume Next
    Target.AddComment
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Target.Comment
        .Visible = False
        If Not IsEmpty(oldVal) And Not IsError(oldVal) Then
            .Text CStr(oldVal)
        Else
            .Text "Previously blank or an error"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting "Previously blank or an error" this in the comment box when i update the cell values and still my edits log sheet not getting any data regarding my updations.

Comment: Even if you change a non-empty cell?

Comment: Yes even with a non-empty cell.

Comment: I tried again now and this time the comment box is displaying the oldvalues of the cells now i Need to find why this updates are not getting recorded in the Edits Log Excel sheet.